# mysql - adding alias columns as a new column

Tags: mysql, alias, query

I have the following mysql query...

```
select x.timest,     
    max(case when x.devloc='outside' then x.value end) as outside,     
    max(case when x.devloc='hvac_main_return' then x.value end) as hvac_main_return,     
    max(case when x.devloc='hvac_main_supply' then x.value end) as hvac_main_supply     
from sample x where date(timest) = curdate() 
group by timest     
order by timest desc;
```

It gives me output like this:

```
+---------------------+---------+------------------+------------------+
| timest              | outside | hvac_main_return | hvac_main_supply |
+---------------------+---------+------------------+------------------+
| 2021-01-28 23:59:54 | 24.8000 |          67.4375 |          82.9625 |
| 2021-01-28 23:58:45 | 24.9125 |          67.1000 |          80.8250 |
| 2021-01-28 23:57:42 | 24.9125 |          66.0875 |          78.2375 |
| 2021-01-28 23:56:33 | 24.9125 |          64.9625 |          74.8625 |
| 2021-01-28 23:55:32 | 25.0250 |          62.3750 |          73.0625 |
| 2021-01-28 23:54:17 | 25.0250 |          62.8250 |          74.7500 |
+---------------------+---------+------------------+------------------+
```

Does anyone know how I can add the difference between hvac_main_return and hvac_main_supply as another column?

EDIT:  More info as requested:

```
mysql> show create table sample\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: sample
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `sample` (
  `property` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `devloc` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sensortype` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timest` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` decimal(8,4) NOT NULL,
  KEY `property` (`property`),
  KEY `devloc` (`devloc`),
  KEY `sensortype` (`sensortype`),
  KEY `timest` (`timest`),
  KEY `value` (`value`),
  KEY `timest_2` (`timest`,`devloc`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Could you please provide the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE sample\G` and some sample data and your desired result for that data.

Comment: Question updated with show create output.  Sample data is what's reflected in the current output... I'm just trying to figure out how to subtract the two hvac_main_* columns and build a new column.

Comment: Sorry - your version of MySQL is also critical to any question - should be included in **any** RDBMS related question!

Comment: MySQL v5.7.11 running on Solaris 11.4 x64

Comment: Check out my comment under @DanBlack's answer - and the fiddle with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select x.timest,     
    max(case when x.devloc='outside' then x.value end) as outside,     
    max(case when x.devloc='hvac_main_return' then x.value end) as hvac_main_return,     
    max(case when x.devloc='hvac_main_supply' then x.value end) as hvac_main_supply,
    ((max(case when x.devloc='hvac_main_return' then x.value end)) -     
      (max(case when x.devloc='hvac_main_supply' then x.value end))) AS diff
from sample x where date(timest) = curdate() 
group by timest     
order by timest desc;
```

If you want a more detailled answer, please provide some sample data as in the fiddle I've done [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f32b3f31b730e5e88fd6db8a0f4a5444). Also, please provide your desired result here - always provide everything you include in any fiddle here also ([linkrot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot)).

Comment: Both answers were excellent and produced the desired results.  I gave the "answer" to this one because it seems to perform better in my environment.  Thanks so much to you both!

Comment: @mikem - try looking at performance using MySQL version >= 8.0.18 - EXPLAIN ANALYZE!

Answer (score 1):

By wrapping the current query as a subquery:

```
SELECT timest,
       outside,
       hvac_main_return,
       hvac_main_supply,
       hvac_main_supply - hvac_main_return AS hvac_main_net
FROM
  (SELECT x.timest,
          max(CASE WHEN x.devloc='outside' THEN x.value END) AS outside,
          max(CASE WHEN x.devloc='hvac_main_return' THEN x.value END) AS hvac_main_return,
          max(CASE WHEN x.devloc='hvac_main_supply' THEN x.value END) AS hvac_main_supply
   FROM sample x
   WHERE date(timest) = curdate()
   GROUP BY timest) AS y
ORDER BY timest DESC;
```

So `GROUP BY` is in the subquery because its needed to give an effect to `max`, however the `ORDER BY` is outside the subquery as it would be ignored in the subquery (the order of a subquery isn't important, to the result, only the outer query).

Comment: Thank you dan... When I run the query in your answer, I get the following error: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT x.timest,
          max(CASE WHEN x.devloc='outside' THEN x.value END) A' at line 6

Comment: Missed a `FROM` while editing. Back there now.

Comment: I did it [this way](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=36cf630a3d1a0871bece9ffa519f1f68) - compare the plans (implicit assumption - 5.7 plans are [similar to | the same as] 8.0 ones). Might have inverted the values - just switch them!

Comment: Thanks Dan and Verace.  When I run each of your queries with "limit 800" added, there is a huge discrepancy in performance.  Dan's query takes 10mins 31 sec, where at Verace's query only takes 0.7sec.  If I don't use limit and just let them pull the complete dataset, they both run about the same, between 10-11 mins.  Why does one query outperform the other by such a high margin when "limit" is used?

Comment: look at `EXPLAIN {query}` output differences. The area of query optimization is continually evolving.